# Possible to read in a DataFrame, convert results to in-code DataFrame instance?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a project which will regularly need to reference six n x 2 tables of different lengths. Each entry in the tables is accurate out to 12 decimal places and needs to be so. While working on the project, I've been reading the tables in from an Excel file at the start of the code, but this will eventually need to be compiled into an executable for my coworkers. So as not to send them an exe with a second Excel file labeled "keep me available in the same folder, trust me!" I'd like to simply instantiate the tables and their values directly in the code.

My question is: will I have to type out each 18 digit value for each entry in each table by hand into the code? Or is there a way to read an Excel file in as a DataFrame, and somehow turn that into the instantiating code that would generate the same DataFrame independently from the Excel file?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try manually creating this in your code to see what happens?

Comment: are you looking for [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: I'm currently using pd.read_excel(), but I don't want the code to rely on reading the dataframes in from an outside source every time it runs.  However, it's unfeasible to type out every entry in the dataframe into my code to remove that dependence.